# Не противоречит ли setFlash в YII MVC?

Tags: php, yii

Доброго времени суток. 
Когда есть необходимость вывода особого сообщения в yii, например, об успешном заполнении формы, приходится совать setFlash в action контроллера, который обрабатывает форму. 
То есть вывод зашивается в контроллер. Если человек, который будет работать после меня захочет поменять это сообщение ему придется лезть в контроллер (если он вообще догадается). Вопрос: не противоречит ли это MVC?

Comment: лично я в первую очередь смотрю на контроллер, чтобы узнать логику вывода. Думаю ничего страшного нет.

Comment: чем больше я узнаю о yii тем меньше оно мне нравится.

Comment: А чем вы пользуетесь? Небольшое описание в сравнении с yii если можно. Был бы признателен.

Comment: Это мне на будущее.

Comment: Yii никой то странный фраемворк. В котором что бы что то сделать иногда приходится такой венегред понаписать, что потом самому стыдно.

Answer (score 1):

На askdev ответили почти также:
Long story short: разделение MVC невозможно реализовать в полной мере в удобном виде. Валидация модели, которая должна работать на самом низком уровне и не иметь с выводом ничего общего, возвращает уже сгенерированные сообщения об ошибках.
При желании можно сделать таблицу вывода и в setFlash записывать только код сообщения, но это будет только муторней.

Answer (score 1):

В своих проектах я использую архитектуру с применением классов помощников Service{ClassName}.php

Для всех flash сообщений на проекте у меня есть отдельный класс ServiceFlash. Все сообщения находятся в этом файле, что упрощает поиск и редактирование этих сообщений. Выглядит он примерно так:

```
class ServiceFlash extends ServiceAbstract
{
    public static function error()
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('errorFlashContainer', "Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Попробуйте еще раз");
    }

    public static function addSuccessfull()
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('mainFlashContainer', "Запись успешно добавлена!");
    }

    public static function saveSuccessfull()
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('mainFlashContainer', "Изменения успешно сохранены!");
    }

    public static function deleteSuccessfull()
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('mainFlashContainer', "Запись успешно удалена!");
    }
}
```

Соответственно в контроллере остается только вызывать эти статические методы

```
ServiceFlash::addSuccessfull();
```

Answer (score 0):

У если вы хотите идеально все, то лучше вынести в файл. Но можно и так, так как на практике эти тексты меняются не чаще чем дизайн сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Ну это не будет противоречить MVC никак.

Главное комментируй код, чтобы можно потом было все четко понять.

Такие сообщения можно делать и не через setFlash т.к. формы можно обрабатывать ajax'ом и в JS посылать данные, а получать сообщения, их и выводить и нет необходимости постоянно отправлять форму и перезагружать страницу.

Comment: Думаю вопрос исчерпан приведенными здесь ответами в целом.